# How to hide label in a listview if text is empty

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm trying to set the visibility of a Label contained in a ListView.
If str01 in empty I need to hide Label

page.ts

```
items.push({
    str00: var00,
    str01: var01,
    str02: var02,
    str03: var03
});
console.log(items);
myViewModel.set("items", items);
```

console.log(items) -- part of the output

```
 [{
   "str00": [
     "VALUE00"
   ],
   "str01": [
     ""
   ],
   "str02": [
     "4.00"
   ],
   "str03": [
     "VALUE03"
   ]
 }, {
   "str00": [
     "AAAAA"
   ],
   "str01": [
     "VALUE01"
   ],
   "str02": [
     "15.00"
   ],
   "str03": [
     "AB09UT"
   ]
 }, ...
```

page.xml with all the ListView

```
<ListView items="{{ items }}"> 
  <ListView.itemTemplate>
    <StackLayout>
        <GridLayout columns="8,120,*" rows="80" height="80" horizontalAlignment="center" borderRadius="8">
            <StackLayout col="0" class="" backgroundColor="lightgray"></StackLayout>
            <StackLayout col="1" class="" backgroundColor="" orientation="horizontal" style="padding:20px 0;">
                <GridLayout rows="auto,auto" verticalAlignment="center">
                    <Label text="titl." fontStyle="italic" style="padding-bottom:0;" horizontalAlignment="center" row="0"/>
                    <Label text="{{ str02 }}" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;padding-top:0;" horizontalAlignment="center" textWrap="true" row="1"/>
                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout col="2" class="" backgroundColor="" orientation="horizontal">
                <GridLayout rows="auto,auto,auto" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="" class="bleft">

                    <Label text="{{ 'Title: ' + str00 }}" style="padding-bottom:0;" horizontalAlignment="left" style="padding:0;" row="0"/>

                    <Label text="{{ 'Title: ' + str01 }}" style="padding-bottom:0;" horizontalAlignment="left" style="padding:0;" visibility="{{ str01, str01.length === 0 ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }}" row="1"/>

                    <Label text="{{ 'Title: ' + str03 }}" style="padding-bottom:0;" horizontalAlignment="left" style="padding:0;" row="2"/>

                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

visibility doesn't work. I use an Android emulator.

How can i solve it?

Thanks a lot!

thank you

Comment: Seems like your `visibility` binding is wrong - you have `str01.length` twice with a comma! Try with just `visibility="{{ str01.length ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"`, or perhaps filter your array in JavaScript with `items.filter(item => item.str01.length)`.

Comment: Hi Igor, i tried with: visibility="{{ str01.length ? 'collapsed' : 'visible' }}" and visibility="{{ str01.length === 0 ? 'collapsed' : 'visible' }}", and they don't work. 
I didn't understand how to use javascript filter. The strange thing is that if I do text="{{ 'Title: ' + str01.length  }}" output is "Title: 1" but str01 in empty :(

Comment: Can you share a playground with your code?

Comment: If you want label to be hidden, then this is still right approach. Try `visibility="{{ str01, str01.length === 0 ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }}"`. Collapse may not work as expected on iOS while reusing cells, so you must use multiple templates, one with label and another without.

Comment: I edited my question by adding some more details. {{ str01, str01.length === 0 ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }} don't work.